# Check if current time is in between given time and day names in Java

Tags: java

The scenario is as follows.

You have to check if the current time is between a given start day + time and end day + time. A specific date range is not given, and the range can be in two different days.

Example:

```
String startDayAndTime = "SATURDAY 17:00";
String endDayAndTime = "SUNDAY 17:00";

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatForTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatForDay = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
simpleDateFormatForTime.setTimeZone(timeZone);
simpleDateFormatForDay.setTimeZone(timeZone);

String deviceTimeString = simpleDateFormatForTime.format(date);

String deviceDayString = simpleDateFormatForDay.format(date).toUpperCase();

// TODO boolean isValidDayRange =
boolean withInRange = deviceTimeString.compareTo(startDayAndTime.split(" ")[1]) >= 0 && deviceTimeString.compareTo(endDayAndTime.split(" ")[1]) <= 0;
if (isValidDayRange && withInRange) {
      //do something
}
```

This above code I'm working on can check for the time but not the date.
How to achieve this? TIA.

PS: Real world example: A shop offers discount for a product on every weekend from 5PM Saturday to 5PM Sunday. Trying to check the current time is eligible for that.

Requirement Update: Has to be in Java 1.7 or lesser

Comment: You have only created format for Time and Day not for the date so i think you also have to create SimpleDateFormat object for Date as well and then try it

Comment: `SATURDAY 17:00` I think it does not look like the correct time, like `SATURDAY`, it what week? next week or last week? Or last 2 week? ...

Comment: @GauravRai1512 I can't have a specific date as this range will recur every week.

Comment: @DangNguyen Urm, it's like this, the current time should be in between whatever the given start and end day name + time.

Comment: How do you define "between" if there is only a weekday and time given? Any moment can be regarded as "between" if the second date is in the next week.

Comment: @Henry Hey, if assumed the two given days are from the same week?

Comment: How is the "same week" defined then? Some countries start a week at Monday, others at Sunday.

Comment: @Henry what if we used a `Calendar` instance and set the start of the week as `MONDAY`?

Comment: You posted not working code. For example `date`, `startDayAndTime` variables not initialize. Edit you code please

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi `startDayAndTime` and `endDayAndTime` strings are already added. `date` is taken from `Calendar.getInstance(timeZone);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use calendar here

```
 Calendar startDateTime=Calendar.getInstance();
    startDateTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.SUNDAY);
    startDateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,1);
    startDateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    startDateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    System.out.println("start Date : "+startDateTime.getTime());
    Calendar endDateTime=Calendar.getInstance();
    endDateTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,Calendar.FRIDAY);
    endDateTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17);
    endDateTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    endDateTime.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    System.out.println("end Date : "+endDateTime.getTime());

   Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

   if(today.after(startDateTime) && today.before(endDateTime))
   {
       System.out.println("Yes");
   }
```

But here you have need to maintain order of day because calendar WEEKS start with SUNDAY and ends with SATURDAY. So you have to follow this Order. Smaller is startdate and bigger is end date.

Order is like this

```
/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Sunday.
 */
public final static int SUNDAY = 1;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Monday.
 */
public final static int MONDAY = 2;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Tuesday.
 */
public final static int TUESDAY = 3;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Wednesday.
 */
public final static int WEDNESDAY = 4;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Thursday.
 */
public final static int THURSDAY = 5;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Friday.
 */
public final static int FRIDAY = 6;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Saturday.
 */
public final static int SATURDAY = 7;
```

But I think it is enough to serve your requirements.

Comment: consider using an enum for the WeekDays if you don't want to use `DayOfWeek`

Comment: this enum is from Calendar Object you dont need to create this type of enum.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the date as below

```
    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now();

    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now();
    ld = ld.with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY));
    LocalDateTime previousMonday = ld.atTime(17, 00);

    LocalDate ld2 = LocalDate.now();
    ld2 = ld2.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY));
    LocalDateTime nextSunday = ld2.atTime(17, 00);
```

You can write your logic after that.

As above you can find previousMonday and nextSunday.

if previousMonday and nextSunday time gap less than a week, you are in the gap. Otherwise you are in out.

Comment: Hi @darshakat, problem is I wouldn't know if the start date would come before. `previous` returns the previous instance of the required day right? Ex: Today can be Friday and the range can be in Monday to Wednesday. So in reality the previous Monday isn't valid.

Comment: @NimilaHiranya first check the previousMonday and nextSunday time gap should be less than one week. like wise you can create your logic

Comment: @NimilaHiranya previous Monday and next Wednesday date gap should be less than a week. Then you are in the time gap. otherwise you are out. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in `java.time` to represent a day and a time (à la [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html)) but we can quite easily define our own. I have chosen a [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) and a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html). Make sure you validate that the time is non-negative and is less than 24 hours.

Note that `DayOfWeek` has a natural ordering of Monday (lowest) to Sunday (highest).

```
class DayTime implements Comparable<DayTime>
{
    private final DayOfWeek dayOfWeek;
    private final Duration time;

    //...

    public int compareTo(final DayTime o) { /* ... */ }
}
```

We can then define an event which specifies a start and end time. Make sure to validate that the start is not after the end.

```
class Event
{
    private final DayTime start;
    private final DayTime end;

    //...

    boolean isTimeDuringEvent(final DayTime dayTime) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I have left the implementation details up to you. It's your assignment.

We can use these classes like so:

```
final DayTime start = new DayTime(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, Duration.ofHours(17));
final DayTime end = new DayTime(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, Duration.ofHours(17));
final Event event = new Event(start, end);

final LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
final DayTime test = new DayTime(
    now.getDayOfWeek(),
    Duration.ofNanos(now.toLocalTime().toNanoOfDay())
);
System.out.println(event.isTimeDuringEvent(test));
```

If you need to take user input as a string then I would advise you to work on getting the logic correct first (as above, with hardcoded values such as `DayOfWeek.SATURDAY`) and *then* when you're sure that that works, work on parsing the input. (you'll probably want [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for this)

Answer (score 1):

## Using TemporalAccessor

You can use TemporalAccessors and a DateTimeFormatter to read the values and then build simple comparators to check your work.

```
String startDayAndTime = "SATURDAY 17:00";
String endDayAndTime = "SUNDAY 17:00";
    
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE HH:mm");
    
TemporalAccessor tempNow = LocalDateTime.now();
TemporalAccessor tempStart = format.parse(startDayAndTime.toLowerCase());
TemporalAccessor tempEnd = format.parse(endDayAndTime.toLowerCase());
    
Comparator<TemporalAccessor> dayCompare = (a, b) -> a.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK) - b.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_WEEK);
Comparator<TemporalAccessor> timeCompare = (a, b) -> LocalTime.from(a).compareTo(LocalTime.from(b));
Comparator<TemporalAccessor> dateCompare = dayCompare.thenComparing(timeCompare);
    
if (dateCompare.compare(tempStart, tempNow) >= 0 && dateCompare.compare(tempNow, tempEnd) >= 0) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answers and the conversations. I managed to solve the issue from both `TemporalAccessor` and `Calendar` options given. Later a new requirement was given as to the util class I was working on has to be written in Java 1.7 or lesser since it was to be a library for an android app which didn't support Java 1.8. Hence the answer by @flopcoder was accepted, on the grounds where Sunday was taken as the beginning of the week and the logic was only to be applied on ranges within one week only.

Answer (score -1):

You have written the code to check only day and time,  not written the code to check date use simpleDateFormat and send the system current date to check and compare,   you are passing "HH: mm" Which will give you system current time  and "EEEE" Will give you day, .... So u need to pass "dd"  to get current system date only and then compare as per you requirement